# Linear mixed models for repeated weight measurements with random slopes: no model will correctly predict negative slopes

Tags: lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

I have a dateset with 120 subjects with associated weights, captured for at least 20 days during a treatment.

I wanted to use the weight on the first day (weight_0), the blood pressure and the main diagnose of each subject to predict their possible weight trajectory.

I am using a linear mixed models (from lmer4 in R) for this. Theoretically, I think that a random slope on days per subject is critical here, as some subjects loose weight and some subjects gain it. So, I came up with the formulation bellow:

```
weight ~days + diagnose + weight_0 + bloodpressure + bloodpressure*diagnose*weight_0 + (1+days|subject)
```

The independent variables in the model were found after testing the significance of including them with anova(model_with_variable,model_without_variable). Only weight, days and subject are series, the others are constant vectors (same value replicated for each weight point).

This model nonetheless does not converge. It will converge if I remove the random slope 'day' or if I simplify weight to make it relative: weight = weight-weight[0]. Both options are sub-optimal.

I also used builmer to find a simplified version of the model above, by following this tutorial: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/buildmer/vignettes/buildmer.html
Resulting on:

```
weight ~ 1+ days + weight_0 + (1+days|subject)
```

**Bottom line:** none of these models will predict positive slopes.

I used predict() (from lmer4) on subjects in which the model was trained, and also in new testing subjects, in both cases resulting in a positive slope when the underlying data clearly has a negative trend.
I thought the problem would be to have less weight loss examples than weight gain ones. Though, replicating the weight loss time series with added Gaussian noise (to add variability) did not change anything.

Sure there is a silly error/assumption somewhere, but my knowledge on LMM is a week old and for such I am unable to debug further.

Comment: The chances that we can figure out what's going on without a reproducible example are pretty small ... have you read `?lme4::convergence` for suggestions on dealing with convergence problems?

Comment: Perhaps this is an ordinary mediation/confounding/Lord's paradox issue: what happens if you fit a linear regression?  (By slope do you mean slope with respect to time?)

Comment: If I fit a linear regression such as weight = slope*days+intercept to each person's weight series it works correctly. Though, I thought I could come up with a general model with lmm, considering all subjects, while understanding the correlations among variables. I meant slope in respect to time.

Comment: How would you suggest I could control for the initial weight value (I read about the Lord's paradox)? I included it in the formulation, but I don't know how to inform the model that weight_0 is indeed the first weight point in the series.

Comment: It's not impossible, but it's really hard, to figure out what's going on without seeing the data. Can you share an (anonymous/fuzzed) version ?  Can you show us some pictures of the data?